# Passing a value from a HTML dropdown to a button to fire up a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to pass a value which is selected by the dropdown on to a button (data-target) so i can show modals dynamically. I'm generating the modals with PHP so everything will be generated automatically.

So whenever a user selects a dropdown, value gets passed to the `<button data-target"xx">`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-2 nopadding'>
      <div class='form-group nomarg'>
         <select class="shop-name select2">
            <option value="1">Shop 1</option>
            <option value="2>">Shop 2</option>
            <option value="3">Shop 3</option>
         </select>
      </div>
    </div>

   <div class='col-md-1 nopadding'>
     <div class='form-group nomarg'>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-
          toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">+</button>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I know how to pass a value from dropdowns to input fields, but passing a value from the dropdown to a button data-target is bit tricky. What's the best way to achieve this?

Below given code is the code i used to pass the dropdown `data-price` value to a input field.

**Passing a value from a dropdown to a input field**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.select2').select2();
    });

     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('select.material-price').change(function() {
        var materialValue = 
       $(this).select2().find(":selected").data("price");
       $(this).closest('.row').find('.material-
        total').val(materialValue);
       });
      });
   </script>
```

Comment: Have you attempted it yourself? Can you please show the code you have so far?

Comment: I have and it didn't work out. Can i do some edits to the same code i use to send a value from a dropdown to an input field? @WouterBouwman

Comment: You could, @Rachel. But I think it's better if you take a look at the answer of Zakaria Acharki.
He shows you an easy way to bind a change event which will change the target attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery you've just to attach on change event to the dropdown the change the value of the button like :

```js
$('.shop-name').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').find('.btn-info').attr('data-target', '#myModal'+$(this).val());

  //Just for test purpose
  console.log($(this).closest('.row').find('.btn-info').attr('data-target'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class='col-md-2 nopadding'>
    <div class='form-group nomarg'>
      <select class="shop-name select2">
            <option value="1">Shop 1</option>
            <option value="2">Shop 2</option>
            <option value="3">Shop 3</option>
         </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='col-md-1 nopadding'>
    <div class='form-group nomarg'>
      <button type="button" id='target-btn' class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but tried this but it didn't work. It didn't change or add a value to 'data-target="#myModal" ' did i miss something?

Comment: also there will be multiple rows included (multiple dropdowns and buttons). Maybe that's why it doesn't work?

Comment: Check now I've changed my code to work with multiple nested elements.

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work. Even the code you have provided in the snippet doesn't assign the value to the button data-target attribute. :S @Zakaria

Comment: You can see in the console output that the value of the `data-target` change when you change the selected option on the list, don't you ???!!

Comment: Yes i do. But it doesn't change or add a value for the data-target attribute.

Comment: How that !!! the console shows the `data-target attribute` and you could see it change, so why you still say _But it doesn't change or add a value for the data-target attribute._?? where you see that it doesn't ?

Comment: I know but change the drop down values in the example snippet you have given me and inspect the button and see whether the value changes or not. For some reason it doesn't change or have any affect.

Comment: The `data()` function doesn't affect the console view, and that doesn't matter at all what matters is the value of the attribute when you get it using `.data('target')`... you could use `.attr()` to change the view `$(this).closest('.row').find('.btn-info').attr('data-target', $(this).val());` but what the meaningfulness.

Comment: It still doesn't change for some reason. Maybe this would work? ` $(this).closest('.row').find('.btn-info').attr('data-target'‌​,'#myModal', $(this).val()); `

Comment: No the suggested code in my previous comment is tested and  should work, you may have an anormaly in your code..

Comment: Check my update, I think the problem comes from the name of the modal, check and let us know it it works...

Comment: YES. Now it works. Thanks. Yes like you mentioned it was definitely the name of the modal.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach but this will work i tested it out. :)

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class='col-md-2 nopadding'>
     <div class='form-group nomarg'>
         <select class="shop-name select2">
          <option data-link="#100000" value="#10">Material A</option>
          <option data-link="#400000" value="20>">Material B</option>
          <option data-link="#500000" value="30">Material C</option>
         </select>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-md-1 nopadding'>
       <div class='form-group nomarg'>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success shop-value">Hello</a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.shop-name').change(function() {
     var shopValue = 
        $(this).select2().find(":selected").data("link");
        $(this).closest('.row').find('.shop-value').attr('href' 
        ,shopValue);
    });
   });

</script>
```

Comment: no sorry it doesn't change the #myModal value when i select it from the drop down.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki ah my bad. I think what she's trying to do is assign the drop down value to the end of data-target="#myModal" so it can fire up multiple modals. 

http://jsfiddle.net/34pp1s8r 

I created the fiddle using your code to match her example. Have a look for some reason your code doesn't assign the value selected from the dropdown to the button data-target.